# How do I call networkx.add_node(..) with optional properties?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, graphml

I'm looping through a dictionary of objects constructed from JSON, and I'm creating vertices from them using networkx. The problem I'm experiencing is that some of the JSON object have missing properties, and if I do this:

```
self.graph.add_node(valueToCheck, 
                id=self.vertexDict[valueToCheck], 
                namespace=component["namespace"], 
                tenant=component["tenant"], 
                type=component.get("type")+"Component",
                artifactFileName=component.get("artifactFileName"),
                className=component.get("className"),
                userConfig=component.get("userConfig"),
                sourceType=component.get("sourceType"),
                sinkType=component.get("sinkType"))
```

then I can't export my graph using `nx.write_graphml(..)` because some of the vertex properties have the value `None` (which is the expected output of `component.get(..)` when the property is missing).

How do I use networkx to construct vertices when some of my properties might be missing in the JSON objects?

Here's what my JSON looks like:

```
[{'type': 'function',
  'namespace': 'campaigns',
  'name': 'campaign-record-transformer',
  'tenant': 'osp',
  'artifactFileName': 'osp-functions-1.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar',
  'className': 'com.overstock.dataeng.pulsar.functions.CampaignRecordTransformer',
  'inputs': ['persistent://osp/campaigns/campaign-manager'],
  'logTopic': 'persistent://osp/logging/pulsar-log-topic',
  'output': 'persistent://osp/campaigns/campaign-records'},
 {'type': 'function',
  'namespace': 'campaignsTest',
  'name': 'campaign-metadata-transformer',
  'tenant': 'osp',
  'artifactFileName': 'osp-functions-1.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar',
  'className': 'com.overstock.dataeng.pulsar.functions.CampaignMetadataTransformer',
  'logTopic': 'persistent://osp/logging/pulsar-log-topic',
  'output': 'persistent://osp/campaigns/campaign-metadata-output'}]
```

Notice that the `inputs` property is missing from the second object. In the actual data, there are at least 8 optional properties that can be missing in different combinations, and there are hundreds of objects like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I do not have the reputation for a comment, so despite this not being a full answer, I am posting it as such*

Have you tried simply excluding the properties that are missing from your `add_node` step?

That is, instead of providing a key value pair where the value is `None`, don't provide a key/value pair at all if the key is missing.

You can probably achieve this quite easily by loading your json using python and then just unpacking your component:

```
components = json.load(...)
for component in components:
    self.graph.add_node(value, **component)
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists